# Deserialize JSONP with Jackson

Tags: java, jsonp, jackson

For some reason Jackson 2.3.0 is unable to parse a JSONP response.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'my_json_callback':
```

I've got the deserialization process to work without the callback.

I've tried with the Jackson JAX-RS package which includes a `@JSONP` annotation, but this seems to be used only when serializing.

Comment: well, I tried with a custom deserializer, but the exception is thrown before the call to the deserialize method is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've been able to remove the callback part of the JSONP response.

First, Jackson is able to parse the JSON even when it ends with a parenthesis. So, by simply removing the `my_json_callback(` from the response is enough.

Since I'm using Apache's HTTP Client, this fixes the issue:

```
String callback = "my_json_callback(";
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
r.skip(callback.length());
return mapper.readValue(r, MyObject.class);
```

The idea is not having to convert the Reader to a String and then parsing that String after removing the callback part.

I was also able to accomplish the same results using `JSONTokener` from `json.org` library for a given JSONP String:

```
JSONTokener t = new JSONTokener(json);
t.nextValue(); // skip the callback
return mapper.readValue(t.nextValue().toString(), MyObject.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trimmed-for-space version of the solution I came up with using a `ReaderInterceptor`. I am using Jersey 2.x in conjunction with Jackson to interact with a web service that only outputs JSONP.

```
public class CallbackStripInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {

    private final static byte[] callbackBytes = "callback(".getBytes();

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    int howMany = callbackBytes.length;

    InputStream x = context.getInputStream();

    if( !(x.available() >= howMany) ) {
        return context.proceed();
    }

    x.mark( howMany );
    byte[] preamble = new byte[ howMany ];
    x.read( preamble );

    // In case the first part of our entity doesn't have the callback String, reset the stream so downstream exploiters get the full entity.
    if( !Arrays.equals( preamble, callbackBytes ) ) {
        x.reset();
    } 

    return context.proceed();
}
```

Use like so:

```
Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .register( new CallbackStripInterceptor() )
    .build();
```

Using this client, all responses with an entity will go through this interceptor (Jersey does not run interceptors on responses without entity bodies).

Answer (score 0):

If your using feign,you can use below solution.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import feign.InvocationContext;
import feign.Response;
import feign.ResponseInterceptor;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class JsonpResponseInterceptor implements ResponseInterceptor {

    private final String identifier;

    @Override
    public Object aroundDecode(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws IOException {
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(invocationContext.response().body().asInputStream(),
                invocationContext.response().charset());
        LOGGER.debug("response is :"+resp);
        if (resp.startsWith(identifier)) {
            String substring = StringUtils.substringBetween(resp, "(", ")");
            Response modifiedResponse = Response.builder().body(substring, invocationContext.response().charset())
                    .headers(invocationContext.response().headers())
                    .protocolVersion(invocationContext.response().protocolVersion())
                    .reason(invocationContext.response().reason()).status(invocationContext.response().status())
                    .request(invocationContext.response().request()).build();
            return invocationContext.decoder().decode(modifiedResponse, invocationContext.returnType());
        } else {
            return invocationContext.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```